# Intermittent slowdowns after changing RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance

Today I upgraded to 32 GB of Ripjaws V 3200MHz CL14 memory for my Windows 10, Ryzen 3600, MAG X5770 Tomahawk Wifi system. Trying to tune the memory settings ended up with the system not posting so I had to clear the CMOS. As best as I can tell, these are the only two changes from before. My problem is that during normal use the computer will slow down to a crawl with the mouse moving only barely and in jerky movements. I've noticed this behavior on Youtube with Firefox but can't rule out it happening elsewhere as it's somewhat infrequent and random. A quick Memtest64 didn't give any errors nor can I see anything weird going on in resource monitor when it's happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: a simple reinstall of mouse drivers looks like it might have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can check

*Clean your mouse sensor!

Reseat RAM , check if seated , if ok , try changing slot.
*Run Memtest /Windows memory diagnostic to find faulty module , Check if module is on your motherboard RAM QVL.

*Power Options via  Control Panel-> Win+R ->type Control  Panel ->Power Options , check if on high performance

*Run DPC latency check to find faulty drivers ->  Download & Run http://www.resplendence.com/download/LatencyMon.exe

*Did you install AMD chipset drivers or  other drivers check you motherboard website for latest drivers.

*Did you update your bios to the latest AGESA version?

*Check system/GPU temp via HWInfo

*How old  is your PSU is it ATX v2.4 compliant

Report back on your findings.

Comment: After finding nothing wrong with my RAM I decided to first reinstall my mouse drivers (duh) before going any deeper. I've been unable to reproduce the unwanted behavior after a few hours of use so I'm going to tentatively call the problem solved.